# Multiple checkbox search query fetching data from database in php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a multiple checkbox search query which fetches data from database. Below is the code:

HTML code:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="cloth_color[]" value="Red" /> Red <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cloth_color[]" value="Yellow" /> Yellow <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cloth_color[]" value="Blue" /> Blue <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cloth_color[]" value="Green" /> Green <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cloth_color[]" value="Magenta" /> Magenta <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cloth_color[]" value="Black" /> Black <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cloth_color[]" value="White" /> White <br>
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$checkbox1 = $_POST['cloth_color'];  
$chk="";  
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
   {  
      $chk .= $chk1;
   }

if($_POST['cloth_color'] != "") {
$query = "SELECT * FROM clothings WHERE colorofcloth = '$chk'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$colorofcloth = $row['colorofcloth'];

    echo 'The cloth with ' . $colorofcloth . ' color';
    echo '<br>';

}
}
?>
```

Now if I choose one option from the search select box I get query. But if I select two or more color I dont get the query. A help will be really appreciated.

P.S. I do have multiple joins in Mysql query but this is the place I am stuck so presenting as clear question as possible here. Also I intent to convert mysql to mysqli before the launch of this code. Thank you :)

Comment: `if($_POST['cloth_color'] != "")` don't use that, check with `isset()`.

Comment: `$colorofcloth` where was that assigned? You're using the wrong variable here and not using the array at all. Edit: this comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45378397/1

Comment: Your posted code is also missing a closing brace.

Comment: i assigned the variable by editing the question and the missing bracket as well @Fred. Those are the things which will be taken care of, the question is how i get multiple queries by selecting multiple choices.

Comment: If someone edits one of the values on your html page they could wipe your whole database. You should be using prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$checkbox1 = $_POST['cloth_color'];  
$chk="";  
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
   {  
      $chk .= $chk1 . ",";
   }

if($_POST['cloth_color'] != "") {
$query = "SELECT * FROM clothings WHERE colorofcloth IN($chk)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$colorofcloth = $row['colorofcloth'];

    echo 'The cloth with ' . $colorofcloth . ' color';
    echo '<br>';

}
?>
```

you can try this code which will use IN() of MySQL where you can pass multiple , separated values.

Hope this helps

Comment: If i choose "Red" and "Blue" it takes as "RedBlue" and if i put a comma at $chk1.','; it takes as "Red,Blue,"

Comment: Get rid of the foreach and use $chk = join(',', $checkbox1) instead. You also need to wrap each value in a pair of single quotes.

Comment: @DhavalChheda i have replied to my own question with some modifications. But your IN clause was a great help in that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Deadron no sir join did not work. I applied single quotes when defining $checkbox1 and didnt worked. I also tried at $chk = join(",", "'".$checkbox1."'") didn't worked either. However i got the solution and have posted answer to my question. It's working so it's fine with me. Thank you for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to use is the [Mysql IN CLause](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm).

For this example, i am assuming that you use the correct syntax for the elements inside de IN Clause.

The correct syntax would be all the values that you need separated by commas, if you select red and blue.

```
$chk = 'red, blue'
```

Using the 'IN Clause' this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clothings WHERE colorofcloth = '$chk'";
```

should transform to this.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clothings WHERE colorofcloth IN ('$chk')";
```

I do not know much about PHP, but for a database stand it should work.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: no not working sir. If i choose "Red" and "Blue" it takes as "RedBlue" and if i put a comma at $chk1.','; it takes as "Red,Blue,"

Comment: i have replied to my own question with some modifications. But you IN clause was a great help in that. Thank you very much.

Comment: in my example i was assuming you had $chk correct. But check the link i posted to see the structure that should have $chk. i will update the value the post to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what i did. first of all got great help from @Dhaval and @Carlos as wasn't familiar with IN function in Mysql.

```
<?php
$checkbox1 = $_POST['cloth_color'];  
$chk="";  
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
   {  
      $chk .= "'" . $chk1."', ";
      //This is important as it is not the number it is a word so it should have a single quote if in query we are using double quote or vice versa.
   }
$check_e = rtrim($chk,", ");
//Although i havn't checked in real time if mysql query will take last comma or not but it is a good practice to remove the last comma by rtrim.

if($_POST['cloth_color'] != "") {
$query = "SELECT * FROM clothings WHERE colorofcloth IN($check_e)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$colorofcloth = $row['colorofcloth'];

    echo 'The cloth with ' . $colorofcloth . ' color';
    echo '<br>';

}
?>
```